# Not enough space or text is aligned incorrectly in Image upload?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, images, uploader

I have noticed that the text  *`to upload your image (max 2 MiB)`* is not getting enough space to fit in the image upload box. In short, you can say, It is not aligned correctly. Here is an image:

[image: bug?]

---

**Zoomed:**

> [image: bug?]

---

**Another zoomed image:**

> [image: bug?]

---

Is it a bug or not or is there a logic behind it? To me it seems to be a bug.

<sup>From my Stack-Overflow post: [Not enough space or text is aligned incorrectly in image upload?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375496/8321664)</sup>

Comment: repro-ed on Chrome / Win 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working on a new responsive version of the image upload and linking experiences, so we won't fix this bug directly. However, if you see a similar problem when our new experience rolls out (ETA a week or so), then please let us know.